# AI emotions vs human emotions

Tags: machine-learning, robotics

Will there ever be differential difference in emotions of humans and a robot? Or will they posses different emotions?

Comment: Some will have the emotions they have been trained to and frozen in ROM, others the emotions they self-learn. Some, placed in extreme conditions, will have emotions we can't experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about philosophy, not computer science.